# How should I prove this direct proof of natural deduction?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

The question is:

```
(A|(B&C)), (A->C)
```

and the goal is to get,

```
C
```

I made (A|(B&C)) into ((A|C)&(A|B)) by using distribution. Then by commutation as well as simplification, I could get (A|C). If I can get ~A, I can do Modus Tollens with (A|C) and directly get the goal, but I spent like 3 hours but could not get the answer... Also I cannot have more premises or assumptions...
How should I resolve this question?
Any help would be very thankful!

Comment: It would help to know what book you're using, so as to know what rules are allowed.

Comment: @quasi, I always assume everbody uses the standard rules (only for $\lnot$ I have seen variations, and that is not relevant here).

Comment: @Henno Brandsma -- Actually, I don't think there is a standard set of rules. It appears to be textbook dependent.

Comment: What about the tag natural-deduction ? distribution, commutation as well as simplification, are not ND...

Comment: There are always introduction and elimination rules. These seem to be constants. @quasi Except $\lnot$ elimination. Introduction always goes: assume $p$, deduce $\bot$, conclude $\lnot p$

Comment: Yes, lots of overlap, but not an exact universal standard.

Comment: Can you prove (C -> C)?  Do you have disjunction elimination?

Answer (score 2):

$1\quad(A \lor(B\ \land C))\quad$Premise

$2\quad A \to C\quad$ Premise

$3\quad(A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$ Distribution Law (1)

$4\quad(A \lor C)\quad$ Simplification (3)

$5\quad(\neg \neg C \lor A)\quad$ Double negation and Commutative Law (4)

$6\quad \neg C \to A\quad$ Equivalence for Implication and Disjunction (5)

$7\quad \neg C \to C\quad$ Hypothetical Syllogism (2, 6)

$8\quad C \lor  C\quad$ Equivalence for Implication and Disjunction (7)

$9\quad C\quad$ (8)

It's easy to see that $C \lor C \equiv C $ is a tautological equivalence. Numbers to the right correspond to the premises on which that line depends. Notation is based on Patrick Suppes  book [Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486406873).

Answer (score 0):

In "my" (i.e. the version I learnt) version of natural deduction this could go :

1. $(B \land C)$ (assumption)
2. $C$ ($\land$ -elimination)
3. $(B \land C) \to C$ ($\to$-introduction,drop 1.)
4. $A \to C$ (axiom)
5. $(A \lor (B \land C))$ (axiom)
6. $C$ from $(\lor$-elimination and 3,4,5)

Done. 
This corresponds nicely to how you would give the argument to a person: 
either $A$ holds, and then $C$ does, by $A \to C$, or otherwise even $B \land C$ holds, so certainly $C$ holds. So always $C$ holds.

Comment: The OP indicated that additional assumptions were not allowed, so your step 1, though perfectly fine in a normal context, is not legal in this context.

Answer (score 0):

$$A \lor (B \land C)$$
$$\implies (A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$$
Introducing $A\implies C$ means that:
$$\implies (C \lor B) \land (C \lor C)$$
$$\implies (C \lor B) \land C$$
$$\implies C$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct natural deduction proof in a Fitch-style proof checker.

[image]

The two premises are on the first two lines. The first premise is a disjunction so I attempt to use [disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) (vE) by considering both cases. The first case $A$ and [conditional elimination or modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) (→E) allow me to derive the goal $C$. The second case $B \land C$ using [conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) (∧E) allow me to also derive the goal $C$.

Since I can derive $C$ in both cases, I use disjunction elimination on line 7 to derive the goal.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/